# Managing reference-like members with shared pointers

Tags: c++11, reference, smart-pointer

It is a well-known fact that there is no built-in mechanism that prevents member fields that are references from being invalidated, even if they are const. (For more background see: https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

The easiest solution is to only use non-reference member fields, and I am sticking to this wherever suitable.

However, for the following reasons, it may not be a suitable solution sometimes:

a) Polymorphism: we need references if we do not know the exact type at compile time.

b) The class is supposed to modify a particular object, not a copy of it.

c) Copying may be expensive.

Whenever a reference is unavoidable, I suggest the following rule: always let the ctor take it by pointer, not by reference. Thus the caller knows better what to expect.

For increased flexibility, I came up with the following idea, that uses shared pointers. It allows the object to be passed-in by reference, then it is copied. It also allows the object to be passed-in by shared pointer, then it is in fact shared between the object and the caller. The following code demonstrates it. Classes derived from class `A` are used for the member field in class `B`. Two constructors for class `B` are provided: one takes a shared pointer and the other take something else and makes a shared pointer out of it.

```
class A {
    public:
    int count = 0;
    virtual void id() = 0;
};
class A1 : public A {
    public:
    void id() {
        ++count;
        std::cout << "A1" << std::endl;
    }
};
class A2 : public A {
    public:
    void id() {
        ++count;
        std::cout << "A2" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
    private:
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
    public:
    template <typename T> B(std::shared_ptr<T> const& arg_a) : a(arg_a) {}
    template <typename T> B(T const& arg_a) : B(std::make_shared<T>(arg_a)) {}
    void operator()() { a->id(); }
};
```

We can pass-in objects:

```
auto a1 = A1();
auto a2 = A2();
auto b1 = B(a1);
auto b2 = B(a2);
b1(); std::cout << a1.count << std::endl;
b2(); std::cout << a2.count << std::endl;
```

This prints:

```
A1
0
A2
0
```

The 0s are expected since `a1` and `a2` are copied by `make_shared`.

It works with temporaries:

```
auto b1 = B(A1());
auto b2 = B(A2());
b1();
b2();
```

Here we pretend that when declaring `a1` and `a2`, we do not yet know of which type they will be:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a1, a2;
a1 = std::make_shared<A1>(A1());
a2 = std::make_shared<A2>(A2());
auto b1 = B(a1);
auto b2 = B(a2);
b1(); std::cout << a1->count << std::endl;
b2(); std::cout << a2->count << std::endl;
```

This prints:

```
A1
1
A2
1
```

The 1s are expected since we are actually sharing `a1` and `a2` with the objects from class `B`.

The following works as well:

```
auto a1 = std::make_shared<A1>(A1());
auto a2 = std::make_shared<A2>(A2());
auto b1 = B(a1);
auto b2 = B(a2);
```

Any suggestions or objections?

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused by all this. The Sutter post you link doesn't mention invalidating references anywhere, but you seem to have assumed that references are somehow more dangerous than raw pointers or regular C++ values, and then there's all this shared_ptr stuff for no clear reason ("flexibility" is not a clear reason). What problem are you actually trying to solve? And why all the effort to avoid references in favor of more expensive but no-less-fallible mechanisms?